# Laravel 5.1 HasMany Relationship Issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables posts, comments and likes.
One post can have multiple comments and one comments can have multiple likes. How can I define relationship between 3 tables to fetch all posts details, including comments and likes of particular post_id in laravel 5.1?

Tables in DB

1. posts

   - post_id
   - post_detail
2. comments

   - comment_id
   - post_id
   - comment
3. likes

   - like_id
   - comment_id

Comment: post cant have likes?

Comment: Yes normally posts have likes rather then comments. This is just the elaborate of relationship, so how can i define such type of relation? and has many relation with multiple tables?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done is several ways. I have implemented in following way keeping two pivot table for 1. post-comment 2. comment-like. However this way may not be the best way, but it works. My tables looks like...

1) comment table.

```
class PostCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');

            $table->string('comment_owner_username');
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

2) like table.

```
class CommentLikesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comment_likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_comment_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary(array("post_comment_id", "user_id"));
        });
    }
```

**NOTE** you need to add the `Model` class and all other codes required to make this work porperly. This is only the database migration part.